# floating point bug in embedded system

Tags: c, embedded, unsigned-integer

On a Rabbit microcontroller..
(1)
 I am incrementing f1 every second by converting into hours to the existing value and store in the same register.

```
void main()
{
    float f1;
    int i;
    f1 = 4096;
    // Assume that I am simulating a one second through each iteration of the following loop
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        f1 += 0.000278; // f1 does not change from 4096
        printf("\ni: %d f1: %.06f", i, f1);
    }
}
```

(2)
 Another question is when I try to store a 32-bit unsigned long int value into float variable and accessing it does not give me the value I have stored. What am I doing wrong?

```
void main()
{
    unsigned long L1;
    int temp;
    float f1;

    L1 = 4000000000; // four billion
    f1 = (float)L1;

    // Now print both
    // You see that L1: 4000000000 while f1: -4000000000.000000
    printf("\nL1: %lu f1:%.6f", L1, f1);
}
```

Comment: Concerning your second question:  The output on my machine is "L1: 4000000000 f1:4000000000.000000", not "-4000000000.000000".  Suggest either 1) Your complier is faulty, 2) Code posted is not the true code or 3) (outside chance) `void main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: The simple rule to memorize is that *float* is capable of storing up to 7 accurate digits.  Your increment is too small, it needs a type that can store at least 8 digits.  You'll need *double* or scale by 3600 so you can use an integral type.

Comment: (1) Code posted is the actual code ran and its output. (2) I believe that int main(void) is not always required on an embedded system as there is no host OS monitoring this program return code

Comment: I don't have double data type in the system. If I increment in whole numbers then they add up fast and could roll over at some point. I need a way to keep the number growing forever, if at all possible.

Comment: You don't have floating point hardware on your system at all - it is all emulated in libraries with integer operations. Consider scaling for integer arithmetic in large types.  Also consider an ARM cortex M4... they are pretty cheap now from a wide variety of vendors.

Comment: Chris, You are correct int is 16-bit. Without the suffix, UL, I am able to store and print long value correctly. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Chris, you are right. On Rabbit, there is no floating point h/w. But switching to ARM is on the road map but is not going to happen right away. It takes time to design h/w board prototype, test, etc. But I need some way to resolve this now.

Comment: Chris, I have added the L1 = 4000000000UL; and ran the program again but the result is the same: L1:4000000000 f1: -4000000000.000000

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is that single precision (32 bit) binary floating point is good for only approximately 6 significant figures in decimal.  So if you start with 4096.00 anything less than .01 cannot be added to the value.  Using double precision will improve the result at some significant cost.

It is usually unnecessary and inappropriate to use floating point, it is very expensive on a processor without an FPU - especially an 8 bitter.  Moreover your literal approximation of one second in hours (1.0f/3600.0f hours) will introduce significant cumulative error in any case. You may be better off storing time in integer seconds, and converting to hours where necessary for display or output.

The second problem is less clear, but seems likely to be an issue with the Rabbit compiler implementation of floating point or possibly of the `%f` format specifier in the `printf()` implementation. Check the ISO compliance statement in the compiler documentation - there may be restrictions - especially on floating point.  Again you may find that using a double resolve the problem - especially as strictly that is the type expected by the `%f` format specifier in an ISO conforming implementation.  As I said, you are probably best off avoiding floating point altogether on such a target.

Note that if you are using Rabbit's *Dynamic C* compiler, you should be clear that Dynamic C is not an ISO conforming C compiler.  It is a proprietary C-like language, that is *similar* enough to C to cause a great deal of confusion! Specifically it does not support double precision (`double`) floating point.

Answer (score 1):

`f1 += (1/3600);` should be `f1 += (1.0f/3600.0f);`.

If you perform integer division then result will also be integer.

Comment: +1 Yes, this was a key problem in the *original* posting of the question - though it has since been edited to remove that particular problem (that the poster then fixes the problem you point out *does not* invalidate your answer).